# Using a basic shader in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, shaders

Looking at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders, I have decided to try these shaders:

```
    String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;\n"+
                            "uniform mat4 u_projectionViewMatrix;\n"+
                            "void main()\n"+
                            "{\n" +
                            "gl_Position =  u_projectionViewMatrix * a_position;\n"+
                            "} ";
    String fragmentShader = "void main()\n"+
                        "{\n"+
                            "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"+
                            "}";
    ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    _batch.setShader(shader);
```

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_projTrans'
>   in shader

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Are you trying to find a uniform called `u_projTrans` somewhere in your program?

Comment: It'd be nice if you added the drawing code where you try to assign to your uniform matrix. It looks as if you might have some code trying to set `u_projTrans` when your vertex shader has `u_projectionViewMatric` as Soapy mentioned.

Comment: @Soapy: I am not doing anything else. I simply copy-pasted the example shader code from the tutorial I linked.

Comment: @Omega it's not the shaders that are the problem, you're doing something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the shaders.

The error you're getting is due to somewhere in your program your calling a line similar to this:

```
shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", matrix);
```

Basically this error is thrown when either `u_projTrans` doesn't exist in that `shader` or it does exist in the `shader` but you don't use it. When it's not used [the shader compiler will optimize away unused uniforms.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430929/1111040)

Comment: In that page, they don't specify what is the value of `matrix`. What am I suppose to use for it? I'm just rendering a `Sprite` object in my batch.

Comment: Matrices are used for affine transforms

Comment: So I don't need one and therefore I don't provide it. Also the shader program is not using anything called `u_projTrans`, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: You will need one if you want to translate, rotate and scale easily. And considering your shader is already using a projection matrix it looks like your shader is geared up to use a modelview matrix.

Comment: You're gonna need to post more code if you want people's help

Answer (score 1):

You are most certainly trying to use your shader in SpriteBatch. SpriteBatch is setting up the shader's projection matrices, which are by convention (as MadEqua answered) called u_projTrans, not u_projectionViewMatrix (see [SpriteBatch source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L132)). SpriteBatch also uses some more uniforms which you must declare (and use, so they aren't optimized away).

However, there is a way how to stop libGDX from crashing when it is trying to set non-existent uniforms and that is by setting [pedantic flag](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.java#L84) to false:

```
ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying to find an `uniform` in the shader called `u_projTrans` to send it the projection matrix.

The simplest fix is changing this shader line:

`"uniform mat4 u_projectionViewMatrix;\n"+`

to

`"uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n"+`

Then the variable names should match on both the application and shader sides.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already pointed out in their answers, `SpriteBatch` expects specific uniforms in the shader and you should either rename them or set the pedantic flag to false.

**I just wanted to add**, that both those things didn't help me solve this error.

The solution was this paragraph from the documentation:

> You can ensure that the shader compiled properly via
>   shader.isCompiled(). A compile log can be spit out using
>   shader.getLog().

*Turned out, my shader didn't even compile properly, because it had a syntax error.* So, always make sure to call `shader.isCompiled()` and `shader.getLog()`